# Unable to see the production database's View contents

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In the development environment, I am able to see the selected view contents, but in the production environment, I can't, please help me here.

Comment: You mean, you don't see any data when you `select * from that_view`? If so, then there's no data in the view.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your view actually.
For example if your view has a filtering for a context value and if you have that context value in your sheet that you run your query, it shows you the data. But if you do not have it on the sheet of you run production query, you may not see it.